# Modifying Peterson algorithm

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency, semaphore, mutual-exclusion

I know that the default implementation of Peterson Algo. provides me - Mutual exclusion, Progress and Bounded Waiting.

The normal Peterson algo is below.

```
bool flag[0]   = false;
bool flag[1]   = false;
int turn;

P0: flag[0] = true;
    turn = 1;
    while (flag[1] && turn == 1)
    {
        // busy wait
    }
    // critical section
    ...
    // end of critical section
    flag[0] = false;


P1: flag[1] = true;
    turn = 0;
    while (flag[0] && turn == 0)
    {
        // busy wait
    }
    // critical section
    ...
    // end of critical section
    flag[1] = false;
```

I wish to perform some modification to this version.

1) The statements flag[0] = TRUE and flag[0] = FALSE in process P0 are interchanged, and similar changes are made in process P1.
Will this algo provide me - Mutual exclusion, Progress and Bounded waiting. - I feel Mutual exclusion won't be supported by this algo. Can any one provide me more info on this?

2) The statement while (flag[1] && turn = 1) in Peterson’s solution is changed to while (flag[1] or turn = [1] ) and analogous changes are made in process P1. Which properties of the critical section are violated by the resulting system and why? - This would still have Mutual exclusion, but I doubt on Progress and Bounded waiting. Can any one provide me more info on this?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Why do you want this? It is an interesting intellectual exercise, but real machines have their own (much more efficient) instructions on which to build synchronization. Also check out [The little book of semaphores](http://www.greenteapress.com/semaphores) by Downey.

Comment: Yes. I have an exercise to solve and its interesting that this makes my concepts clear.

Answer (score 1):

See this Paper

[On Variations of Peterson's Mutual Exclusion Algorithm](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs5860/2011fa/documents/Graham-OnVariationsOfPetersonsAlgorithm-Aug30.pdf)

> ### Abstract
>
> In 1981 the most
>   concise version presented for two concurrent
>   processes was Peterson's Algorithm. Peterson used
>   the OR operator in the decision control.
>   Tanenbaum uses a claimed version of Peterson's
>   Algorithm that uses the AND operator in the
>   decision control and there is no resetting of the
>   flags. We show that this AND version leads to a
>   trivialization of Peterson's original form. The first
>   cycle, which looks interleafed, reverts to batch
>   processing. Since batch processing is in serial
>   order, this eliminates the need for a mutual
>   exclusion algorithm designed for concurrent
>   processes. Using Peterson's original OR operator
>   and resetting the flags as he does, every run is
>   interleafed. Furthermore, as should be expected, a
>   DeMorgan on the Peterson control operator yields
>   an AND version that sustains the interleafing
>   identical to Peterson's original form. However,
>   this form is clearly not simpler than the original
>   OR form. It requires three additional NOT
>   operators and the flags must still be reset.

Answer (score 0):

1. In order to provide mutual exclusion, you would also need to change the while loop condition for the flag to

```
while(flag[1] == 0 && turn == 1)
```

2. It can create deadlock. If both processes set their flag to true at the same time and then busy wait on the while loop, then none of them will be able to proceed further.